# Getting VBE Information

Tags: nasm, osdev, vesa

Recently , I began using vbe for graphics in my OS. When in real mode, the vbe info block structure returns a pointer to the video mode list. When i view this pointer's hex value, it looks like this: It is a douleword value

```
0x7bb24220
```

I am wondering how the data at this address can be gotten in real mode , since I can't access that address. Does any one have an idea how this can be done?

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before adding them. The [tag:vbe] tag is for the Visual Basic Editor, which has nothing to do with the question you've asked here.

Comment: @KenWhite, I meant vesa BIOS extensions, actually. Anyway , changed it to 'vesa'.

Comment: Thanks. Reading the tag description would have let you know it wasn't the proper tag. :-)

Comment: `0x7BB24220` (bytes 0x20, 0x42, 0xB2, 0x7B) would be "offset 0x4220 in real mode segment 0x7BB2", which would be the 32-bit physical address `0x7BB2<<4 + 0x4220 = 0x0007FD40`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually not a usual pointer but a so called `vbeFarPtr` which has an segment:offset format. For more information see the [VBE Specification](http://www.petesqbsite.com/sections/tutorials/tuts/vbe3.pdf) (page 20).